# range of data in a list based on the index of the values in another list

Tags: list

I am trying to print a range of data in a list based on the index of the values in another list:

```
d=[10, 14, 18, 30, 40]
s=[2, 4, 5, 6, 7]    
print (s[d.index(d>=14)])
```

I get TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'. This is the simplified problem that I have in a big code. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = [10, 14, 18, 30, 40]
s = [2, 4, 5, 6, 7]

print([s[d.index(item)] for item in d if item > 14])
#print [5, 6, 7]
```

I think you may want something like above?